# Why won't my boiled egg whites harden?

Tags: eggs, egg-whites

I'm having problems with boiling eggs. The egg whites are not hardening and stay soft, but the yolks did set. The eggs I'm using are freshly laid.
What can cause this? How can I make sure my egg whites set too?

Comment: Please share some more detail about how you are cooking these eggs.

Comment: In a stainless steel pot  . Bring water to the boil then gently place eggs into the water for 3to4minutes

Comment: Could it be the chickens are lacking something

Comment: Lacking what? Spirit of cooperation?

Comment: @Greenie the egg white proteins set at lower temperatures than yolk proteins.  So it's possible the chickens are low in protein in their feed.  This time of the year (winter/early spring) is usually harder regarding feed (per Michael Pollan, Omnivore's Dilemma)

Comment: Thanks mandomando I will try adjusting their feed  and see what happens

Comment: @Greenie I think you should make your response an answer.  It sounds like the most reasonable explanation offered so far

Answer (score 2):

This is not a real answer, but rather some info to hopefully, help:

- Egg whites are 90% water, when they harden, the protein unravels and creates a grid network that does not allow the molecules to slip past each other.  If the protein level drops, it might make it harder to set and stay runny.
- Egg white proteins go through a phase change (become hard) at a lower temperature than the Yolk by a few degrees, that's how you can have soft-boiled eggs.
- If you crack a fresh egg and it sprawls on the dish (as opposed to hold tall), you're looking at an egg from a chicken that didn't eat many insects/larvae. ;) This may be expected as at this time of the year (northern hemisphere) insects aren't very active.

There is a good section in Michael Pollan's Omnivore's Dilemma that gets into more detail.  And perhaps better information regarding the off-season feed.

Answer (score 1):

What intrigues me is **what happens in the cooking of an egg already open?**

**Have you tried doing an egg "poached"?** You should be able to see directly the cooking, since it lacks the shell. "In fashion", the egg is cooked by pouring it, without shell, in boiling water, with a flick but delicate. The white should be fully cooked, but the yolk remain raw.

Theoretically, **you should see the white cooking, while the yolk not.**
Please try it and tell us the result.

Comment: I wouldn't make that assumption about egg whites and yolks just based on their relative protein content.  The biological processes involved in making the egg may not prioritize the yolk and white the same.

Answer (score 0):

I never had a cooked yolk and raw whites. Try what I usually do --> put the eggs in water together and wait for 5-10 mins. below is the guideline for boiling eggs. don't wait till the water boils before you put the eggs.

Egg Size    Degree of Doneness   Time Required
Medium      Soft-cooked yolk     3 minutes
        Medium-cooked yolk   5 minutes
        Hard-cooked yolk     12 minutes

Large    Soft-cooked yolk   4 to 5 minutes
     Medium-cooked yolk     6 minutes
     Hard-cooked yolk   17 minutes

Extra Large     Soft-cooked yolk    5 minutes
            Medium-cooked yolk  7 to 8 minutes
            Hard-cooked yolk    19 minutes

Comment: Given that the yolks are cooking and the whites aren't, the problem is definitely not cooking times. If the cooking time were too short, the yolk wouldn't set either.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.thekitchn.com/5-mistakes-to-avoid-when-making-hard-boiled-eggs-cooking-mistakes-to-avoid-216999

Eggs could be too fresh. I just made this mistake and searched for why my eggs were mushy...

Comment: Welcome Johanna - Link only answers are discouraged: *Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.* You can edit your post to include this information, by clicking the edit link at the bottom of your post.

Answer (score -1):

i have been boiling and poaching eggs for many years and this is the first time I have not been able to cook the White of an egg, so I don't think it's the cooking process but to do with the chicken's productive system

Comment: I just had the same thing happen to me this week with an organic egg from a local farmer. It was strange because the yolk was fully firm, yet the white was not runny but soft in the shell

Comment: This got flagged - I think it's marginally an answer (something to do with the chicken, not the cooking) but it's not a really good answer (what's that something?).